# Handling Bank information on Website (Not Storing)

Tags: security, https, mean-stack, transfer, onlinebanking

I have website using MEAN stack and is accessed over HTTPS. I want the user to input their bank account details but I don't want to store the bank details (since I think there may be liability and security concerns). The information will then be sent to a 3rd party website like Transferwise where I can send over money to the user bank account.

My question is are there any security precautions that I need to take when I have the user input data on my website?

Comment: It is usually easier to redirect the customer to the payment site (for example, paypal) or embed the payment form in an iframe in your application. That way, bank accounts won't be sent to your application and you won't have to worry about security issues related to having that kind of information in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked a very broad question and thus will get a broad answer in return. Not persisting any data in the database helps a lot, but you could still fail due to logging sensitive data out on your server side or due to server/TLS misconfigurations.

You probably would want to be [PCI DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) compliant (or at least be aware that such a thing exists and how your application relates to this standard). Fulfilling [OWASP ASVS](https://owasp.org/www-project-application-security-verification-standard/) at least Level 1 requirements would be good as well.